# A property named "locale" in my API response body is being overridden in some browsers

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch

I have an API returning this kind of payload in its response body:

```
{ "id": 1, "name": [{ "locale": "en", "value": "example" }] }
```

I'm calling this API using the following code in a React web app:

```
async function getAsync(url) {
  return fetch(url, {
    method: "GET",
    mode: "cors",
    credentials: "include",
    headers: {
      ...commonHeaders, // Just for auth
    },
  })
}

async function getResponse() {
  const url = `...` // API url
  let res
  try {
    res = await getAsync(url)
    switch (res.status) {
      case 200:
        const resBody = await res.json()
        return Promise.resolve(resBody)
      ...
      default:
        return Promise.reject(new GenericError())
    }
  } catch (err) {
    return Promise.reject(new GenericError())
  }
}
```

The problem is the following: When I print in console `JSON.stringify(resBody)` I get the correct payload (of course as a JSON string), but if I print `resBody` its property `name.locale` has *my* locale ("it") instead of "en"!

Why is it happening? What's going on here???

This happens in both Firefox (85.0.2) and Chrome (88.0.4324.150) but NOT in Safari (14.0.2).

Answer (score 1):

I've found the reason! It was a nasty side-effect present in a completely different asynchronous function in my UI, caused by these very wrong comparisons (please notice **=** used instead of **===**):

```
{
  name_en: name.filter(item => item.locale = "en").value || "",
  name_it: name.filter(item => item.locale = "it").value || "",
}
```